# Matching a list of possible hashtags in a tweet - Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

Firstly I've looked at a lot of posts on Stackoverflow but I don't see one which seems to be the definitive way. Someone always seems to find a flaw in the regex.

I already have retrieved my tweets and obviously they can contain any number of hashtags in each one.

If I have an array of possible hashtags that I want to find - ["#ENGLAND","#IRELAND","#wales"] etc.

What is a RELIABLE way to check if a tweet contains these hashtags. I don't want to call the API again, I only want to check my existing tweets, as I'm clicking on buttons to change the filtering on the fly, want to avoid rate limit if they keep clicking around for ages.

EDIT:

Example: Here is a tweet that contains #ENGLAND and #someothertag

I want to search all the tweets and just show the tweets that CONTAIN one or more of my array of tags, I already cache the tweets, I don't want to make a call containing any tags just filter the existing results!

Comment: The Twitter API includes a field for hashtags, why not cache that when you initially fetch the data?

Comment: Doesn't the twitter api return the hashtags for a tweet in the entities of the response?

Comment: I don't understand, if I have say 4 buttons with different tag names, how can i filter the results without calling the api again?

Comment: @Neil just store the entities as a property of the element where you're storing the tweet, and hide it with jquery

Comment: @menacingly can you give me an example in an answer pls? Like using a data-attribute for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the hashtags from the entities on the element, for instance

```
<div class='tweet' data-hashtags='england ireland'>some_tweet</div>
```

And filter like this when someone clicks your button:

```
$('div.tweet').hide();
$('div.tweet[data-hashtags~="ireland"]').show();
```

It's obviously greatly simplified, but the general approach should help you avoid having to parse out the tags yourself

Comment: OK I understand exactly what you mean here, but how do I know that some_tweet actually contains "england ireland"? I checked the results of a tweet using a http debugger and I can't see anywhere that has these hashtags separate from the actual tweet text!

Comment: @neil which api are you using?

Comment: I'm using JS api to return tweets from one account only eg: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=the_account_here

Comment: @Neil I think you want the include_entities parameter set to true.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: I marked this as correct because you pointed me towards the include_entities which is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Why only hashify particular hashtags (which you need to specify and then maintain) when you can hashify *any* hashtag?

I usually use something like this:

```
var hashregex = /#([a-z0-9_\-]+)/gi,
    text = text.replace(hashregex, function (value) {
       return '<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/#!/search?q=' + value.replace('#', '%23') + '">' + value + '</a>';
    });
```

Then you can just use `text` when you set the content to the processed tweets

Answer (score 0):

```
// match a #, followed by either "question" or "idea"
var myregexp = /#(england|ireland|wales)\b/i;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1]; // will contain "england","ireland", or "wales"
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

If you don't know the names of the hashtags on hand 
replace

```
 var myregexp = /#(england|ireland|wales)\b/i;
```

with

```
 var myregexp = /#(\w+)/; // Use this instead
```